# Ember.js TextField action submits form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ember.js

I have the following form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" {{action "formSubmit"}}>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User:</label>
        {{input type="text" value=user action="findUser"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Notes:</label>
        {{input type="text" value=notes}}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

As you notice, I have two actions for this form:

1. When I type on the user input field and press enter, it fires the `findUser` action
2. When the form submits, the `formSubmit` action is called.

***Now, here's the problem.***

When I type something on the user text field and press enter, it fires the `findUser` action **but** also fires the `formSubmit`. As I know, this is how a form normally behaves. When you press enter on a text field, it submits the form.

Is there a workaround on this behavior? That when I press enter on a the user text field, I want the `findUser` action to be fired but not submit the form.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is removing form itself. You can have action on button. You may have to sacrifice some form related features but still works very well. Here is the jsbin.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nifim/2/edit

There might be some other better way as well.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>User:</label>
        {{input type="text" value=user action="findUser" bubbles=false}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Notes:</label>
        {{input type="text" value=notes}}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" {{action "formSubmit"}}>Save</button>
```

and javascript

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    findUser: function(){
      console.log('Find User');
    },
    formSubmit: function(){
      console.log('Form Submit');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround that allows using the form:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/povud/1/

Just add 'onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;"' to the form element and place the {{action}} on the button itself:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User:</label>
        {{input type="text" value=user action="findUser"}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Notes:</label>
        {{input type="text" value=notes}}
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action "formSubmit"}}>Save</button>
</form>
```